# JQuery dialog not showing up in center of window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, position

I am using JQuery1.7.1, and JQuery UI 1.8.20 libraries
I have also included jquery.ui.position.js in the same bundle.

However, the dialog box is not showing up in center of screen.
It is showing at left:0 in IE 8, and loading up at random position on Chrome/FF
I haven't specified any styling.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true, autoOpen: false, height: 'auto', width: 'auto', resizable: false });
$("#dialog").dialog("open");            
$("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", $('#dialog').attr('data-dialog-title'));
```

Any idea of what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to align center the dialog box:

```
$("#dialog").position({
   my: "center",
   at: "center",
   of: window
});
```

Try if this would work..Refer the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) here